# Account doesn't have permission to suggest edits

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, android-app

I tried to edit [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/818617/usb-reboot-not-supported-by-bios) on SuperUser using the SE Andriod app (v1.0.51) and got the following error in the red bar at the top:

> Account is not allowed to suggest edits.

I get the same error when trying to Preview the edit as well.

I can (and did) successfully submit the edit from the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SE Apps don't support suggested edits (they can't push suggested edits to the review queues). Gain full editing privs and won't have any problems anymore :)

Comment: OK, I did not know that. It would be less confusing if the message said something like _SE for Android doesn't support edit suggestions_.  Or better yet, not even offer the option or permit entry into the _Edit_ screen for accounts lacking sufficient rep to make edits without peer review.

Comment: @Twisty this misleading message is not my fault :D

Comment: LOL. Indeed not. I'm more musing out loud for the benefit of a programmer that's run out of bugs to fix. _hint hint_

Comment: Could you clarify how one should go about gaining full editing privs in reasonable time? Not everybody who wants to participate in a particular SE site has enough subject knowledge to open with a great answer to an unanswered question. Some people want to ask a question first, which means suggesting edits for +2 each to earn meta/chat privileges to ask for clarification of what questions are on-topic in order to avoid a question ban.

Comment: @tepples You can actually suggest edits on any non-locked non-meta post having no pending suggested edits from the site, but cannot do it from the app simply because the api of apps doesn't support suggested edits. And no one forces you to earn full editing prigs :)